# IOS How to download only proper images in a Collection View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

To limit images downloads only to those that are useful (I mean when you're not scrolling too fast), Im using NSURLSessionTask in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and then cancelling it in `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in order not to keep downloading for useless Table View cells.

I didn't notice such an interesting method as `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` for a Collection View.
Is there a specific way to abort useless downloads in the same way for a Collection View without using external APIs, please ?

Thanks in advance for your returns.  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collectionView have already that 2 methods

```
- collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:
- collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:
```

see apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath)

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation:

`collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath: